# Select images and rename with cell value

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a range with images in cell "C". The value I want to rename the pictures is in cell "A".
I have this code, and it works great, but I have to manually change every picture.

Is there a way to automate this?

I have 6000 pictures from products.

```
Sub RenameShape()
    Dim objName
    On Error GoTo CheckErrors
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need to select a shape first"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    objName = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
    objName = InputBox$("Assing a new name to this shape", "Rename Shape", objName)
    If objName <> "" Then
        ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = objName
    End If

    Exit Sub

CheckErrors:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```